# HTML Canvas Compositing: Reveal canvas image underneath another canvas

Tags: html, canvas, mousemove

I'm new to the HTML canvas element, but have been working with it for the last two days. I'm working in Django and my mission is to reveal an image (loaded onto a canvas) that is hidden beneath another canvas (a pure white rectangle) *as the mouse moves over the canvas stack*. Both canvases are the exact same width and height.

I'd also like to be able to set the shape (square or circle) and dimensions of the cursor when it does the "erasing" of the top canvas (reveals the image underneath).

I've taken a look at [the answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085289/discover-hidden-image-by-changing-cover-image-opacity-on-mousemove-event) but am a bit lost on the javascript written in the linked fiddle. My HandleMouseMove function is my initial attempt at trying to identify mouse placement in the top canvas. Any guidance would be really appreciated and thanks in advance. Here is what I have so far:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    //Create Bottom canvas & context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctxB = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    //Create Top canvas & context
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var ctxT = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    //Set waterfall image variable
    var waterfall = document.getElementById('waterfall');

    //Set canvas w&h properties
    canvas.width = canvas2.width = waterfall.width;
    canvas.height = canvas2.height = waterfall.height;

    //Populate Bottom canvas with image
    ctxB.drawImage(waterfall, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Populate Top canvas with white rectangle
    ctxT.fillStyle = "white";
    ctxT.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
}
        
//Show Coordinates of mouse on Top canvas
function HandleMouseMove(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var coords = x + ", " + y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;  
}

//Erase Top canvas to reveal waterfall
```

```css
#stack {
    position: relative;
}
#stack > canvas {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'entrance/entrance.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'entrance/entrance.js' %}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p hidden>
            <img src="{% static 'entrance/Waterfall.jpg' %}" alt="issue here" id="waterfall" />
        </p>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <div id="stack">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            <canvas id="canvas2" onmousemove="HandleMouseMove(event)"></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    //Create Bottom canvas & context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctxB = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    //Create Top canvas & context
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var ctxT = canvas2.getContext('2d');

    //Set waterfall image variable
    var waterfall = document.getElementById('waterfall');

    //Set canvas w&h properties
    canvas.width = canvas2.width = waterfall.width;
    canvas.height = canvas2.height = waterfall.height;

    //Populate Bottom canvas with image
    ctxB.drawImage(waterfall, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //Populate Top canvas with white rectangle
    ctxT.fillStyle = "white";
    ctxT.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
    

    canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
      var x = event.offsetX;
      var y = event.offsetY;
      var coords = x + ", " + y;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;

      //Erase Top canvas to reveal waterfall
      const eraseSize = 15;
      ctxT.clearRect(x - eraseSize/2, y - eraseSize/2, eraseSize, eraseSize);
    })
}
```

```css
#stack {
    position: relative;
}
#stack > canvas {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<p hidden>
    <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/plantsvszombies/images/8/8f/Kiwi_bird.png" alt="issue here" id="waterfall" />
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="stack">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
```

For change shape, set [globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) for top canvas:

```
ctxT.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
```

then draw any shape you want. For example, a circle:

```
ctxT.beginPath();
ctxT.arc(x, y, eraseSize, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
ctxT.fill();
ctxT.closePath();
```

instead of

```
ctxT.clearRect(x - eraseSize/2, y - eraseSize/2, eraseSize, eraseSize);
```

Comment: thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed and I love how small the amount of code is - very elegant. Thanks again for taking your time to help!